# mongoDb. Populate document based on specific name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get some basics in mongo, but I am stuck as I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
So, I have two documents: `Race` and `Building`.
My schema for race looks like this:

```
import mongoose, { Model, Schema, Types } from "mongoose";

export interface IRaceSchema {
  name: string;
  buildings: Types.ObjectId;
  description: string;
}

const raceSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IRaceSchema, Model<IRaceSchema>>(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
    description: String,
    buildings: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Building",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

raceSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: "buildings",
    match: { race: { $eq: this.name } },
  });
  next();
});

export const Race = mongoose.model<IRaceSchema>("Race", raceSchema);
```

In here i have `populate` from my building document.
My `buildingModel` looks like this:

```
import mongoose, { Model, Schema, Types } from "mongoose";

interface IBuildingSchema {
  name: string;
  description?: string;
  race: string;
  buildingType?: string;
  level: number;
  bonus?: string[];
}

const buildingSchema = new mongoose.Schema<
  IBuildingSchema,
  Model<IBuildingSchema>
>(
  {
    name: String,
    description: String,
    buildingType: String,
    level: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1,
    },
    bonus: [String],
    race: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["orc", "human", "elvs", "nekro"],
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

export const Building = mongoose.model<IBuildingSchema>(
  "Building",
  buildingSchema
);
```

My issue is, that I want to populate my Race document with buildings based on race assigned to my building

[image: postman for race]
[image: postman for buildings]

I am using `$eq` but not sure if this is proper way, as nothing is populating

Comment: I've not seen the `populate` syntax with `match` in it before - and I don't see it in the `populate` docs. Typically `populate` works with an array of `ObjectId`s, that will populate the matching model, rather than a generic lookup. It seems the`buildings` array is empty, so nothing is populating.

Comment: i did found this in docs :/ not sure what is wrong here

Comment: can you link in the docs where? `match` can be used with populate, when it is further limiting the data that would already be populated, from the array of ObjectIds. Your array is empty, so it has nothing to populate.

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions here you go. My original attempt was without `match` just assign `path: buildings`

Comment: Yes, that does what I mentioned. It will populate based off the `ObjectId`'s in your `buildings` property, and then filter those down based off your `match` criteria. Given that you have an empty `buildings` array, there will never be any results from the populate.

Comment: yes, i just read what you wrote like in the firs comment. Well all was workin as it should. Issue was me :D